# How to access private Videos with oembed

Tags: dailymotion-api

I have videos embedded on a protected website via the old API.

I want to switch to the new API. All I need is an embed-code for a PRIVATE video.

Normally I would call: http://www.dailymotion.com/services/oembed?url=

But this does not work for a private video.

I already have a mapping-table for the old video-IDs to the new URLs.

I also have an API-Key and API-Secret.

Is there some example code on how to get the embed-URL for a private video via the API with PHP-SDK?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

To request the embed url you can request the `embed_url` field from the api https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-embed_url-field

In php, the call is:

```
$api->get(
    '/video/<videoID>',
    array('fields' => array('embed_url'))
);
```

If your video is private, you'll have to use authentication (https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#authentication) to be able to access embed url information. This section https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools/sdks#sdk-php-authentication will shows you how to do this in php.